# Where can I define java compiler options so that they are seen by any java process running on the machine?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments

Following http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html#28+July+2011+-+WARNING%3A+Index+corruption+and+crashes+in+Apache+Lucene+Core+%2F+Apache+Solr+with+Java+7 I wish to set the `-XX:-UseLoopPredicate` JVM option globally, so that it is seen by all the java processes running on my machine.

How do I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: You have over 100 questions without an accepted answer.  Perhaps you could ask more questions which can be answered or follow up answers so they can be accepted.

Comment: Java compiler options are irrelevant to 'any Java process'. They are only relevant to Java *compiler* processes. Please fix your title, or make up your mind.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try using the [`_JAVA_OPTIONS`](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/javaexe.html#JAVAOPTIONS) environment variable.

Comment: That defines JVM options, not Java compiler options.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PrintFlagsFinal to get all runtime VM options
example `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep "Flag you want to search for"`